# weekly calendar date algorithm

Tags: javascript

```
let currentWeekNumber = 1;  // Initial week number

function getWeeklyDates(year, month, weekNumber) {
    const dates = [];

    // Set the first day of the month
    const firstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);

    // Calculate the offset to the first day of the week (assuming Sunday is the first day)
    const firstDayOffset = (7 - firstDay.getDay()) % 7;

    // Calculate the date of the first day of the week
    const firstDayOfWeek = new Date(year, month - 1, firstDay.getDate() + firstDayOffset);

    // Generate an array of dates for each day of the week
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        const currentDate = new Date(firstDayOfWeek.getFullYear(), firstDayOfWeek.getMonth(), firstDayOfWeek.getDate() + i);
        dates.push(currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
    }

    return dates;
}

function getMaxWeekNumber(year, month) {
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 0);
    const lastDayOffset = (7 - lastDayOfMonth.getDay()) % 7;
    const weeksInMonth = Math.ceil((lastDayOfMonth.getDate() + lastDayOffset) / 7);
    return weeksInMonth;
}

function updateWeekDates() {
    const year = 2024;  // Change the year as needed
    const month = 3;    // Change the month as needed

    const weekDates = getWeeklyDates(year, month, currentWeekNumber);
    document.getElementById("weekDates").innerHTML = `Week ${currentWeekNumber} dates: ${weekDates.join(', ')}`;
}

function getNextWeek() {
    const maxWeekNumber = getMaxWeekNumber(2024, 3); // Replace with the actual year and month
    currentWeekNumber = (currentWeekNumber % maxWeekNumber) + 1;
    updateWeekDates();
}
```

Need to associate every day of the week with a date, but every week has either 4 or 5 weeks, so I need to calculate it before using getWeeklyDates, so I was wondering if there's a better way, or this is the optimal solution. Basically, every time I click next week, the correct dates need to be associated to every day from Monday to Sunday.